# Access HTML data- attribute with JS, WITHOUT using .getelementbyid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me keep is simple.  Scrollit.js, you set a data-scroll attribute on the navigation link, and a data-index where the content you want it to scroll to.

You don't need to set a specific ID on either thing for it to work.  So why when I am reading about using data- attributes, the JS always starts with getelementbyID(#..)?

I'm looking to put together a micro-framework that uses this.

Comment: getElementById is accessing DOM element via id attribute. for data attribute, use that elements `dataset` attribute.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: Appreciated @marmeladze I was reading on the same site, but everything I saw before that kept referencing to use getElementbyID, and then the daa-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways accessing DOM elements.

`$x()` will let you catch nodes with given `xPath` expression.

querySelector will also let you achieve the same result (Type `help()` in firefox console, it will take you to web helpers page).

I like querySelectors, so I'll use them.

```js
var changes_indexes_to_cubes = function() {
  var indexed = document.querySelectorAll("[data-index]");
  for(var i=0; i<indexed.length; i++) {
    indexed[i].innerHTML = parseInt(i)**3;
  }
}


document.querySelector("[data-foo]").addEventListener('click', changes_indexes_to_cubes)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="1">0</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="2">1</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="3">2</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="4">3</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="5">4</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="6">5</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="7">6</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="8">7</span>
    <span class="lorem" data-index="9">8</span>    
    <span class="lorem" data-index="10">9</span>
    <p class="Lorem" data-foo="foo">Click me to change everything</p>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```